# Update data based on parameter with operator from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables with sample data below:

```
tblSale     
PartCode    PartGroup   SaleQty
a   FM  600
b   MM  202
c   SM  10
d   NM  0

tblCondition        
PartGroup   Condition   
FM  >500    
MM  >=200   
SM  >=1 
NM  0
```

in SQL Server stored procedure i want to update `PartGroup` in `tblSale` by `PartGroup` in `tblCondition` based on `sum(SaleQty)` and compare with `Condition`.

Any help please.

UPDATE:

[image]

Example:
PartCode 'A' is has PartGroup='FM' and SaleQty=500.
if SaleQty=400 then update PartGroup='MM' based on Condition in tblCondition.

```
UPDATE tblSale
SET tblSale.PartGroup=tblCondition.PartGroup
WHERE SUM(tblSale.Sale) ??? tblCondition.Condition
```

Comment: explain clearly. update what?

Comment: update PartGroup in tblSale with parameter from tblCondition. if sum(SaleQty)>500 then PartGroup=FM,if sum(SaleQty)>=200 then PartGroup=MM,...

Comment: What's the datatype/data stored in `condition`?  What do you want your final result set(s) to look like?  What query(s) have you tried that aren't working?

Comment: Contion filed is NVARCHAR(50), because it has data '>500','>=200'. this filed is user input for parameter

Comment: get this sum `sum(SaleQty)` you group which column? `PartCode`?

Comment: You can't run comparisons that are encoded as text, you have to have them as actual statements.  Your options are 1) dynamic SQL to build the parse tree pre-run 2) write a stored proc to parse data in-column and return a Boolean result 3) turn it into a range table storing just numbers, and running the same condition on it (which should probably be `>=`).

Comment: Thus i need to separate field Condition into 2 columns, Operator and ConditionValue. Operator='>=' and ConditionValue=500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to do this without dynamic code.

For my solution you will need make some changes/notes:

- change PartGroup `NM` condition `0` to `=0`
- make sure that tblCondition table conditions are inserted from biggest (500) to lowest (0)

First what I do is create `CASE` for every row from tblCondition table.

Then I SUM data to temp table by `PartCode` (I split `PartCode` 'c' to 2 rows for testing)

And for the last, create dynamic code, which will update data

```
/*

CREATE TABLE #tblSale ( PartCode VARCHAR(10), PartGroup VARCHAR(10), SaleQty INT)

INSERT INTO #tblSale SELECT 'a', 'FM', 600
INSERT INTO #tblSale SELECT 'b', 'MM', 202
INSERT INTO #tblSale SELECT 'c', 'SM', 5
INSERT INTO #tblSale SELECT 'd', 'NM', 0
INSERT INTO #tblSale SELECT 'c', 'SM', 5


CREATE TABLE #tblCondition ( PartGroup VARCHAR(10), Condition VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO #tblCondition SELECT 'FM', '>500'    
INSERT INTO #tblCondition SELECT 'MM', '>=200'   
INSERT INTO #tblCondition SELECT 'SM', '>=1'
INSERT INTO #tblCondition SELECT 'NM', '=0'

*/

--CREATE CASES
DECLARE @CaseStr NVARCHAR(1000) = 'CASE '

SELECT @CaseStr = @CaseStr + '
        WHEN SaleSUM ' + Condition + ' THEN '''+ PartGroup + ''' '
FROM #tblCondition

SET @CaseStr = @CaseStr + ' END'


-- SUM data by PartCode
SELECT PartCode, SUM(SaleQty) AS SaleSUM
INTO #tblSaleSUM
FROM #tblSale
GROUP BY PartCode


-- Create dynamic code for update
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @query = N'

UPDATE S
    SET S.PartGroup = SS.PartGroup
FROM #tblSale AS S
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT PartCode, ' + @CaseStr + ' AS PartGroup
        FROM #tblSaleSUM
    ) AS SS
    ON SS.PartCode = S.PartCode

'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
update ts set partGroup = something
from tblSale ts
inner join tblCondition tc 
        on tc.PartGroup=ts.PartGroup
inner join (Select PartGroup, sum(SaleQty) as SumSaleQty
            from tblSale
            group by PartGroup) as sums 
        on sums.PartGroup = tc.PartGroup 
           and sums.SumSaleQty >= tc.Condition
```

Comment: Please learn to format your answers.  The question is somewhat unclear, so I'm not sure this is what the asker needs...

Comment: I'm writing from my phone and I can not format my message as well unfortunately. I will format the answer than I get my computer) Lets wait asker decision about my answer.